# Exodus 20:3 -Deuteronomy 6:4 and 10:17 according to Targum Onkelos

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, aramaic, targumin

Regarding the following passages of the Torah:

"You shall have no other elohim besides Me" (Exodus 20: 3)

“Hear, O Israel: HaShem is our Elohim; HaShem is one" (Deuteronomy 6: 4)

"For HaShem, your Elohim, is Elohe of elohim" (Deuteronomy 10:17)

I would need to know what their translation is in the Targum Onkelos, and also to know the specific Aramaic terms, transliterated into the Latin alphabet, with which Onkelos translates the various references to "elohim", and also the reference to "Elohe", present in the aforementioned passages.

Thank you all

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8859 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56660 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/116851 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56375 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55858

Comment: See [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Targum_Onkelos_to_Exodus/PRC5O_Yp7L0C?hl=en&gbpv=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20:3 אֱלָהּ elah

Deut 6:4 אֱלָהָנָא elahana

Deut 10:17 **אֱלָהֲכוֹן** הוּא **אֱלָהָא** *דַּיָּנִין* וּמָרֵי מַלְכִין **אֱלָהָא** רַבָּא גִּבָּרָא וּדְחִילָא

```
                       elaha     *dayanin* elaha   elahachon
```

What do you mean by "translation"?

Comment: English translation of the version given by the Targum on these passages

Comment: The only time that the Aramaic isn't simply the same word (el-h) is in the third, where the word "elohim" is translated as dayanin, judges.

Comment: So in Exodus 20: 3 Onkelos translates "elohim" with the singular "elah", right?

Comment: I'm not an Aramaic scholar, but that seems to be the case.